# Dynamically call Func<T, object[], object> with Emit

Tags: c#, system.reflection, reflection.emit

i am trying to create functions dynamically that when executed just calls a given Func

```
 public IProxifier<T> Override(string method, Func<T, object[], object> handler)
    {
        if (!overr.ContainsKey(method))
        {
            Ops op = new Ops();
            op.GenericTypes = new Type[] { typeof(T) };
            op.MethodInfo = handler.GetMethodInfo();

            MethodBuilder mb = tb.DefineMethod(method, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.ReuseSlot |
                    MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, typeof(object), new Type[] { typeof(object[]) });

            ILGenerator il = mb.GetILGenerator();


            //il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, op.MethodInfo, op.GenericTypes);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, handler.GetMethodInfo());
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            overr.Add(method, op);
        }
        return this;

    }
```

I am creating a dynamic type using reflection, and everytime this Override method is called i need to create in this Dynamic created object the given method (overriding the prexisting one, i.e ToString() ).

I Have tried in various ways with Emit and EmitCall but all i have been getting is either InvalidProgramException or nothing at all.

What i am trying to achieve is:

- For a given Func, to override a method, that when it is called this Func is instead triggered and its result returned, all with ILGenerator. How can i do this? i have been stuck for days and nothing works.

Comment: Can you add some code on how you plan to use this; I think that will clarify your intention.

Comment: Instead of `il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, handler.GetMethodInfo());` you could try: `il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Func<T, object[], object>).GetMethod("Invoke"));`

Comment: Hmm, what about pushing the parameters onto the stack? The method you are calling requires parameters. Like `T` and the `object[]` before `Callvirt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First problem** is that when you calling method in IL it always take as first parameter object for which method should be called. For static method this parameter is `null` but it still should be present. So first fix is load `null` to stack before other parameters:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull); // method object parameter
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, handler.GetMethodInfo());
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

**Second problem** is that according to `handler` type you trying to call method that requires parameters of type `T` and `object[]` in stack before you call it. Currently you only loading second parameter of type `object[]` so you also should parameter with type `T`.

Depending on what you are trying to do you can solve it in tree different ways:

***Simplest option*** is to add parameter `T` to generated method:

```
MethodBuilder mb = tb.DefineMethod(method, MethodAttributes.Public | 
    MethodAttributes.ReuseSlot | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, 
    typeof(object), new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(object[]) });
```

And then use it's value for calling `Func`:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);  // method object parameter
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // first parameter of type T
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // second parameter of type object[]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, handler.GetMethodInfo());
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

If you ***can't change dynamic method signature*** you can remove `T` from `Func` parameter and path it as another parameter to `Override` method:

```
public IProxifier<T> Override(string method, T someName, Func<object[], object> handler)
```

If you also ***can't change signature for `Func` but you don't use value of `T` in it***, you can just load default value to stack. It could be done easily for reference types by loading `null`:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);  // method object parameter
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);  // first parameter of type T
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // second parameter of type object[]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, handler.GetMethodInfo());
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

But for value types it becomes a bit trickier, you should declare local variable with this type initialize it, then call `initobj` instruction to create value and then load it into stack:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(T)); //create local variable
il.Emit(OpCodes.Initobj, typeof(T)); //initialize it with default value

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);  // method object parameter
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0); // first parameter of type T from local variable
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // second parameter of type object[] from argument

il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, handler.GetMethodInfo());
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```